# Connecting Oracle Autonomous Database to .net entity framework

Tags: oracle, model-view-controller, cloud, oracle-call-interface

I need help on connecting Oracle Autonomous Database to my .net core mvc app,
has any one tried it or aware about it.

Thanks in Advance

Thank You
Shubham Pratap

Comment: Googled "connect .net to oracle autonomous database". [First hit at oracle.com](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-data-warehouse-cloud/user/connecting-microsoft-net.html#GUID-697E5171-F44E-4DF5-9C3F-757D962D6A27) [Second hit at oracle.com](https://www.oracle.com/topics/technologies/dotnet/tech-info-autonomousdatabase.html) [Third hit at oracle.com](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Database/Tasks/adbconnecting.htm)

Comment: Thanks, but i already gone through it , still not able to get it

Comment: There are 3 sample codes provided by Oracle from same links provided by @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica.If you have local instance or Oracle instant client  test with tnsping or connect with sqlplus,if you can connect with sqlplus or tnsping is success you should have no problem connecting with .net core mvc app

Comment: I am not able to connect it, there is oracle entity core framework but not able to get how to use it

Comment: Check this [link](https://github.com/oracle/dotnet-db-samples/blob/master/samples/dotnet-core/ef-core/autonomous-db/adb-odp-efcore.cs). Same concept  managed or unmanaged odp.net or framework

Comment: @Kumar Can you help in what will be datasource to be entered in following connection string                 

optionsBuilder.UseOracle(@"User Id=<USER>;Password=<PASSWORD>;Data Source=<TNS NAME>");

Answer (score 0):

Too long for comments.

Download and extract Oracle cloud wallet.Make a backup copy of tnsnames.ora file.Shorten the names of your autonomous database entry(this step is optional.

Add the path of cloud wallet directory in sqlnet.ora

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)

SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH = yes

WALLET_LOCATION =
  (SOURCE =
    (METHOD = file)
    (METHOD_DATA =
      (DIRECTORY = "c:\OracleCloudWallet")

    )
  )
```

2) Shorten name of autonomous database entry of your choice in tnanames.ora (this step is optional just for convenience sake)

tnsnames.ora file (actual instance name is lengthy over 50 characters)

```
adw_high = (description= (retry_count=20)(retry_delay=3)(address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1522)(host=xxx))(connect_data=(service_name=xx))(security=(ssl_server_cert_dn="CN=xxx,......")))

adw_low = (description= (retry_count=20)(retry_delay=3)(address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1522)(host=xxx))(connect_data=(service_name=xxx))(security=(ssl_server_cert_dn="CN=xxx,......")))

adw_medium = (description= (retry_count=20)(retry_delay=3)(address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1522)(host=xxx))(connect_data=(service_name=xxx))(security=(ssl_server_cert_dn="CN=xxx,............")))
```

3)Create system variable for TNS_ADMIN and directory path to cloud wallet directroy
If you set up tns_admin variable properly

from command prompt `C:\echo %TNS_ADMIN%` should print correct path

4)If all above steps setup properly then you should be able tnsping each entry in tnsnames.ora

Connection string in your code shoulld be like this

```
 // Configure ODP.NET connection string
//Data Source is nothing but adb entry in tnsnames.ora i,e adw_high
 optionsBuilder.UseOracle(@"User Id=xxx;Password=xxxxxx;Data Source=adw_high");


// Set TnsAdmin value to directory location of tnsnames.ora and sqlnet.ora files           

OracleConfiguration.TnsAdmin = @"c:\OracleCloudWallet";


// Set WalletLocation value to directory location of the ADB wallet (i.e. cwallet.sso)
  OracleConfiguration.WalletLocation = @"c:\OracleCloudWallet";
```

Edit:-
Today Fired up ADW instance and connected without any problem.I have Oracle 19c local instance.

ASP.NET Core Web Application relevant code

```
    OracleConfiguration.TnsAdmin = @"C:\app\oracle\product\19.3.0\db_1\network\admin";
    OracleConfiguration.WalletLocation = @"C:\app\oracle\product\19.3.0\db_1\network\admin";
    string conString = "User Id=scott;Password=xxxx;Data Source=adw_low";
```